# Como hacer una resta y actualizar datos de cada fila

Tags: php, mysql, sql

He tenido complicaciones al momento de realizar una operación de resta en mi programa con php.

Tengo `$saldoe` que se resta con `$resultadot`y que el resultado de eso se llama `$nuevo`.

Este es el codigo:

```
<?php
 //conexion a la base de datos y al servidor

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "ALEXANDER1234") or die ("<h2>No se ha encontrado el servidor</h2>");
$db = mysql_select_db("ngi", $link) or die("<h2>Error de conexion</h2>");
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'ALEXANDER1234', 'ngi');

//obtenemos los valores del formulario

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
$aseo = $_POST['aseo'];
$impl = $_POST['impl'];
$luz = $_POST['luz'];
$agua = $_POST['agua'];
$internet = $_POST['internet'];
$rep = $_POST['rep'];
$equipo = $_POST['equipo'];
$dep = $_POST['dep'];
$sueldos = $_POST['sueldos'];
$bono = $_POST['bono'];
$resultadot = $aseo + $impl + $luz + $agua + $internet + $rep + $equipo + $dep + $sueldos + $bono;

$consulta="SELECT sum(cancelado) AS resultado from control_pagos where 1 ";
$resultado = mysql_query("SELECT sum(cancelado) AS resultado from control_pagos where 1 ", $link);
$fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);
$saldoe=$fila['resultado'];   

$nuevo = $saldoe - $resultadot;

$sSql = "UPDATE caja SET saldoe = '$nuevo' Where  saldoe = '$saldoe'";
mysql_query($sSql);

//ingresa la informacion en la tabla

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO caja VALUES('','$aseo', '$impl', '$luz', '$agua ', '$internet' , '$rep', '$equipo', '$dep' , '$sueldos', '$bono', '$resultadot', '$saldoe', '$nuevo')" ,$link);



echo "TODO FUE ENVIADO CORRECTAMENTE";


}else{

    echo "No llego Nada";
}
```

La tabla ***mysql*** es tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`$saldoe` debe restarse con `$resultadot` y lo que de se va para `$nuevo`
y `$nuevo` pasa a ser el nuevo `$saldoe` de la siguiente fila, manteniendo el `$saldoe` anterior en la anterior fila... 
¿Se entiende?

Comment: Un saludo. Ok, entiendo la operación, cual es el bug?. No lo especificas.

Comment: ¿Te has planteado el uso de arrays para simplificar un poco el código?

Comment: aún necesitas ayuda por aquí?

Comment: Ya logre solucionar mi problema, gracias.